# Github API V3のGit Dataでファイルを削除する方法

Tags: github

Github API V3のGit Data API(https://developer.github.com/v3/git/ )を用いて、Github上のリポジトリを操作しています。
ファイルの作成/編集までは出来たのですが、削除ができません。
どのようにすれはいいのでしょうか。

Comment: こちら [GitHub API - delete a file](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#delete-a-file) ではないでしょうか？

Comment: @argus 残念ながら、これじゃないですね。これも検討したのですが、1つ消すごとにコミットが1つ流れてしまうのが個人的にはBADでした。